# parseInt() only works seem to up to 9999

Tags: javascript, parseint

I have 2 fields/HTML values, in a format similar to this: `7,544`  (which represents a monetary amount).

I am removing possible commas using this line:

```
itemBudget = itemBudget.replace(/,/g, '');
```

I am comparing these 2 amounts, and alerting the user if the total amount is higher than the budget. I am using this check:

```
if (parseInt(finalAmount) > parseInt(itemBudget) ) {
   alert('Your total is higher than the budget');
}
```

This works perfectly -but only when the `finalAmount` is up to 9999. If it is from 10,000 and up - the test does not pass, even when the final amount is 10000 and the budget is 5000.

What can be going wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: check what both the values are and what parseInt returns individually for both the values.

Comment: remember to always use the _radix_ (The second parameter) with `parseInt()`. Most of the time it will be `10` which represents base 10 numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you replace **finalAmount** comma as well.

**Working example:**

```js
var finalAmount = "10,001";
var itemBudget = "5,000";
itemBudget = itemBudget.replace(/,/g, '');
finalAmount = finalAmount.replace(/,/g, '');
if (parseInt(finalAmount) > parseInt(itemBudget) ) {
   alert('Your total is higher than the budget');
}
```